# Microsoft SQL Server not letting me open .bak

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am taking a class and our instructor gave us a file to download called cs.bak and its supposed to be formatted for the version of SQL we are using. So I downloaded the one for Microsoft SQL Server.

Well I tried to do the restore but when I get to the part that I choose device and locate the file `cs.bak` it loads and now I am suppose to be able to choose destination. Well after I choose destination I do not have the `OK` button to go through with the restore.

On these instructions http://www.katieandemil.com/sql-server-2012-restore-database-backup-file
If you count the window screens. I can only get as far as the 6th screen.

I am suppose to do this, "Some questions will ask you to write out query results from a database. In order to answer these questions you will need to have the example database available to you."

Well I can't open it to do this. Any help would appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What version of MSSQL are you running, v.s. the version the .bak was created from? The backups have to be from the same version. Mismatched versions cannot be restored.

Comment: I have version 2012. I do not know the version that the instructor is using. Is there a way I can tell from the file?

Comment: SQL Server Express with Advanced Services (contains the database engine, Express Tools, Reporting Services, and Full Text Search) Is the one that I selected to download.

Comment: probably easier to just ask the instructor.

Comment: is the pc likely to have had the database restored before, make sure the data file and the log file don't already exist, if they do you might need to change their path/name

Comment: It has not had it restored before. This is my personal computer and I just tried it. Also I tried to contact instructor but still no answer. Is there a program that will just open it for me?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the "choose destination" screen with missing OK button?

Comment: yes http://imageshack.us/a/img210/6759/sqlimage.png

Comment: How **big** is your `cs.bak` file?? It seems to contain **nothing**....

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[image]

This checkbox might be unchecked - and then the `[OK]` button remains disabled...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Windows Layout issue. To resolve this, reset the SSMS Window Layout by selecting from the main menu Window -> Reset Windows Layout.